# Circular view in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to serve static resources in my Spring controller.
I have a `index.html` file, that should be returned to each request.
My controller is:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Also i added resource handler:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/");
}
```

But at the end i have following exception:

> Circular view path [/index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

I understand, that in my configuration all requests will be handled with my Spring controller.

So when i request for, e.g. `http://localhost/someText`, that request will be processed with my controller, then my controller sends redirect to `//localhost/index.html`, this request goes to Spring's `DispatcherServlet` and then it redirected to my controller again, that causes exception above.

Also I already tried some options: to make web filter, that will process my request to `/index.html` not via spring servlet, but via default one (in my case `DefaultServlet` of undertow), but it's not possible, cause my app is not packaged as war and my `index.html` file located at `/src/java/resources`.

Actually I found, that main problem for me is that in spring's `DispatcherServlet` handler for my request (`//localhost/index.html`) detected as my controller, not resource handler.

```
protected HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    for (HandlerMapping hm : this.handlerMappings) {
        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace(
                        "Testing handler map [" + hm + "] in DispatcherServlet with name '" + getServletName() + "'");
        }
        HandlerExecutionChain handler = hm.getHandler(request);
        if (handler != null) {
            return handler;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So maybe there is a way to change `HandlerMapping`'s order to make resource mapping have higher priority that endpoint mapper?
Or is it possible to exclude request to `/index.html` from my controller to be able to handle it with spring resource handlers?

Comment: You have a `index.html` in `src/main/resources` and want to serve it using that controller?

Comment: Yeap, is it a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that in following way:
I defined requests, that should be processed in some exact controllers.
Then i created Filter, that adds to all other requests prefix "/root" in path. And i made a controller, that processes all "/root/**" requests serving my index.html.

So, basically, when i request "/api/someApi" - so it goes to my controller with API stuff. But when i request "/someStuff/" - in filter it becomes "/root/someStuff/" - so it goes to my controller that returns "/index.html".