# Why does mapping to /** with Spring boot cause a stack overflow exception?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to run a single page web application and map all URLs to index html. I have a non-rest controller which looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*")
public String getIndex()
{
    return "index";
}
```

and this works fine. However, it does not match further forward slashes in the URL. Moreover, if I change the request mapping value from `/*` to `/**`, I start getting stack overflow exceptions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83g4hczCyxgUDZDWTM5R1NLemM/view?usp=sharing.

Does anybody know how I can use `@RequestMapping(value = "/**")` without getting stack overflow exceptions?

**UPDATE**

In jetty it gives the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [/WEB-INF/index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/WEB-INF/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.).
```

[Full stack trace here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B83g4hczCyxgYUtjNUVhTzZ1QWM)

The interesting thing about this message is that it knows that "index" refers to the file "/WEB-INF/index.html". Why can't it just render this view if it knows about it?

I have also found another stackoverflow.com [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185938/circular-view-in-spring-controller) with the same problem. It was asked a year ago and still doesn't have an answer. Furthermore, this used to work in previous versions of Spring.

Comment: Can you add the lines after:

2017-07-15 22:47:13.815 ERROR 4437 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.5.0.[dispatcherServlet]  : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you switch to [Jetty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat) or [Undertow](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-undertow-instead-of-tomcat)?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson by switching to jetty I get the following error: javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [/WEB-INF/index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/WEB-INF/index.html] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem? There are too many unknowns based on what you've described thus far

Comment: Also, judging by your initial description of the problem, the solution you are attempting to use isn't quite right. IMO, this is a better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769200/configure-spring-boot-for-spa-frontend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149315/discussion-between-james-and-andy-wilkinson).